# Instalation of Ubuntu in Virutal box 6.0 memory error

Tags: kubuntu, virtualbox, ram

I have been using Ubuntu for some time. I am trying to install Ubuntu Virtual box. During installation I am getting an error that you din't have enough memory. I am not sure why I am getting this error because I have 16 GB memory on my system.

What is the minimum requirement of memory to install Ubuntu in virtual box.

Comment: I am using Virutal box 6.0 and my system has this RAM. https://www.allhdd.com/hpe-752369-081-memory/

Comment: If this is more info for the question please do not use comments. Edit the question and add it there. Comments are where you get asked questions so people can help you. Ubuntu needs same requirements in a box as not in a box. In the VB setup how much memory have you allowed for Ubuntu?

Comment: Silly question, but how much memory did you allocate for the VM? VirtualBox often starts with some low value like 1GB when creating a VM. It should be 4GB at a minimum if you are installing a Desktop version of the OS.